# Whats wrong with this custom button URL (prepopulating custom lookup field)

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

I have a custom button URL with only two parameters being passed, the record type ID and an ID being passed to a custom Opportunity lookup field

```
/500/e?
CF00NC0000005Au31_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
&RecordType=012C0000000MK5d
```

The lookup field parameter has both the 'CF' prefix (for custom fields) and '_lkid' suffix (for lookup fields). And yet, when I click the button from the opportunity, the custom lookup field on the Case remains empty (both in Edit view and after I save).

The record type is updated appropriately, just FYI.

Also, if I remove the '_lkid' suffix, then the actual opportunity ID *does* show up in the field, but of course returns an error since the lookup can't take actual IDs via the UI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing one other param to which you pass the actual name of the opportunity 
(when you remove _lkid you are passing the lookupfield name = {!opportunity_Id})

Read this blog for thorough understanding on hop to do URL hacking with lookups

> **some ID field:** e.g. CF00…. This corresponds to the ID of the field
>   that you want to be prepopulated. This will always be the text that is
>   displayed in the box.
>
> **{some ID field}_lkid:** e.g. CF00…_lkid. If the field in question is a
>   lookup or master-detail, then this field should be set to the
>   resulting record ID {some other ID field}.  Note that in this case,
>   the actual non _lkid field is irrelevant, and not consulted.

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html

Answer for your question

```
/500/e?
CF00NC0000005Au31={!opportunity.name}&
CF00NC0000005Au31_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}
&RecordType=012C0000000MK5d
```

Should populate the opportunity in the lookup field

Comment: Boom, and it works! Answered so fast I can't even click the answer button yet. BTW, I've seen/read that link you shared about a dozen times now. Seems to be the authoritative source on URL hacking in salesforce on the web right now. That's where I got the clarification on what the CF and lkid meant. But I don't think it says anything about needing both the Name and ID fields passed together, so thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @smohyee most welcome, URL hacking has become more a need than a fancy feature lately :).Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Just create formula field that will have lookup field reference. Now refer formula field like below -

YourLookupField__c={!URLENCODE(SObjectApiName.YourFormulaeField__c)}